# Folder that is bigger on the inside

Tags: unity, disk-usage

I have a folder named `Meteor`. In Unity, when I right-click and display the Properties for the folder, it tells me "2,734 items, totalling 6.1 MB". However, inside this is a hidden folder named `.meteor`. The Property dialogue for this folder claims "673 items, totalling 28.0 MB".

How can a child folder be bigger than its parent? Does the Properties dialogue not display the contents of hidden folders, even when Unity is set to display them?

Is there a special key combination that I can press while choosing Properties, to make it show the real total?

Comment: Do you have 'show hidden files' activated in the nautilus preferences?
In a terminal you can use `du -ms project`

Comment: @muclux That's it! Thanks! I thought using Ctrl-H to toggle the visibility of hidden items in the current foldre would be enough to tell Unity that I want Properties to include information on the hidden items, but I see that I need to use Edit > Preferences and select Show Hidden And Backup Files for this to happen.